# Widows must have been the wife of one man

Tags: 1-timothy

In 1 Timothy 5:9-10

> 9 A widow is to be put on the list only if she is not less than sixty years old, **having been the wife of one man**, 10 having a reputation for good works; and if she has brought up children, if she has shown hospitality to strangers, if she has washed the saints’ feet, if she has assisted those in distress, and if she has devoted herself to every good work.

Does it mean a widow must have not remarried?